# How to create a line chart with median line series in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I need to create a Line Chart using Google Charts API or any JS plugin like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google charts has a trendlines option:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines

Example from their docs:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Diameter', 'Age'],
    [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
    hAxis: {title: 'Diameter'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Age'},
    legend: 'none',
    trendlines: { 0: {} }    // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I've used this with their LineChart without any problems.